# show and hide using angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

```
<div class="m-t-sm">
<app-button [btnText]="'ADD USER'" (click)="!show"  [btnType]="'text'" [btnColor]='"submit-btn-color"'></app-button>
</div>
```

Only when "add user" button is clicked the below div should appear. this code works but I need to know is there any better way to do this.

```
 <div class="selected-code-box" *ngIf="show">
          <div class="row no-margins">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div> ...//code goes.. 
</div>
```

Comment: may you should use something like show = !show at the button click?

Comment: yes you can use it like (click)="show =!show"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but *ngIf is the best way to solve this problem

```
<app-button [btnText]="'ADD USER'" (click)="show = !show"></app-button>

<div *ngIf="show">
      <!-- code -->
</div>
```